# Is there any issue to run multi join in access db

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am trying to run this sql statement in access and found Syntax error

```
Select  * 
from TableC C INNER JOIN TableE E 
on E.TKey = C.TKey
INNER JOIN TableP P on P.TKey = E.TKey  AND E.employee_id = '123'
```

**Error:**

```
syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'E.TKey = C.TKey
    INNER JOIN TableP P on P.TKey = E.TKe'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In access you cannot have multiple joins without separating them with parentheses.

```
Select  * 
from (TableC C 
INNER JOIN TableE E 
on E.TKey = C.TKey)
INNER JOIN TableP P 
on P.TKey = E.TKey  
AND E.employee_id = '123';
```

Comment: thanks! actually the sql works fine when I run for first two tables.even with ( * )

Comment: Thanks! But, putting all joining segments in separate paranthesis fixed it :)

Comment: @BlackCat seems in access you cannot have multiple joins without separating them with parentheses. updated the answer. Try now.